# get last date of year of a given date

Tags: javascript

```js
var reportDateStr = "2018-05-21";
var reportDate = new Date(reportDateStr);
var y = reportDate.getFullYear();
var lastDateOfReportYear = new Date(reportDate.getFullYear(), 11, 31);

console.log(lastDateOfReportYear)
```

Instead of getting the last day of the year 2018 which is Dec 31, 2018, I am getting Jan 31, 2019
Please, can you tell me what is wrong with the above code and why I am getting Jan 31, 2019?

Comment: Most likely because you failed to take time zones into account ...

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Works fine here, in CST time zone: `new Date(2018, 11, 31)` yields `Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

Comment: ^ Was just about to post the same.

Comment: Can not reproduce too. Check your system's timezone.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, without digging deeper into what browser/node version you are using (we will get to why that matters in a moment), I am a bit uncertain as to why you are getting a date a month later (Jan 1, 2019 would make much more sense for the issue you are running into) but I will give a higher level explanation for why Jan 1, 2019 might be happening.

From the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation:

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments.

So because your are constructing a new date with three parameters, the date represents your local time.

```js
const localDate = new Date(2018, 11, 31);
console.log({
  localDate // in EST this will be "2018-12-31T05:00:00.000Z"
});
```

Notice the hours is "05" (for EST) and not "00". Using `Date.UTC` as recommended will make it "00" regardless of local time.

```js
const localDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 11, 31));
console.log({
  localDate // This will always be "2018-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
});
```

A few other things to note when creating a Date from a date string (which is not recommended):

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

So the date generated can be different due to various JavaScript implementations. Check out this [chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for a reference on this issue.

Also note that [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)uses the local time to get the full year value. This can impact your desired output as well.

So, to be a bit more safe you could use UTC for all of your calculations:

```js
const reportDateStr = '2018-05-21';
const reportDate = new Date(reportDateStr); // This could still be problematic
const y = reportDate.getUTCFullYear();
const lastDateOfReportYear = new Date(Date.UTC(y, 11, 31));
console.log(lastDateOfReportYear.toUTCString());
```

There are also libs like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) that can help with the multitude of issues dealing with times and dates.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much work in something is always going to be the same.

December ALWAYS is going to be 31 days and the last month of the year is always going to be december, so why dont you just get the year and append to it `12-31`

Example:

```js
var reportDateStr="2018-05-21";

console.log(reportDateStr.substr(0,4)+'-12-31')
```

Now, If you want to keep your function make sure the TimeZone where you are. Your code works fine with the Eastern Time

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OPs code doesn't work, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

See the working snippet below,
I added some consoling from your code and comments to make it simple:

```js
var reportDateStr = "2018-05-21";
var reportDate = new Date(reportDateStr);
var y = reportDate.getFullYear();
var lastDateOfReportYear = new Date(y , 11, 31);

// For me the below returns the 30th December, 11pm
console.log('Date:', lastDateOfReportYear);

// … because I've got -120 as offset!
console.log('TimezoneOffset:', new Date().getTimezoneOffset());

// You need to use this one to get rid of the Timezones:
var lastDateOfReportYear_2 = new Date(Date.UTC(y , 11, 31));
console.log('Date UTC:', lastDateOfReportYear_2);
```

Hope it helps.